# Error sending bulk email on AWS SES - Error: AccessDenied: User is not authorized to perform `ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail' on resource

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ses, bulk-email

I am having a difficulty sending bulk emails on aws ses.

I can send regular emails (non bulk emails) without any problem.

The error appears to suggest there is a problem with my iam permissions:

```
Error: AccessDenied: User `arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/SSMRoleEc2/Y-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:identity/xyz.com'
```

The full code for the IAM permission is:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail",
                "ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: try with the policy simulator in AWS console; with this tool you can check if your role is corretly authorized to use the ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail functionality.